# Is there a way to filter a string vector based on 'and' and 'or' criteria (using grepl)?

Tags: r, filtering, grepl

I need to filter a list with 196 ultrasonic samples. The names in the list look like *SV-14-001_P*, *SV-14-001_S1*, *SV-20-001_P*, *SV-20-004_S2*. They all start with SV, refering to the company the samples are from. The second number is the diameter of the sample (there are five different diamters, but in th example I only use 14). The third three-digit number is the sample number of the current diameter and the last number refers to the wave type (P, S1 or S2). I want to use the list of samples for a script that picks the S-wave onset or P-wave onset. This means the diameter should be equal and the wave type should either be shear wave S1 or S2 (can be combined in one list) or P.

So far I have managed to filter out based on "and", by simply running the same code twice with a different pattern, but that gives me a list with either S1 samples or S2 samples instead of a list with S1 and S2 samples.  I also tried it with 
        `[grepl("S2\|S2", filt.folders)]`, but that did not work.

```
parent.folder <- "//home.org.aalto.fi/meijsl1/data/Documents/GAGS/Ultrasonic 
data/Ultrasonic data - Plots"
sub.folders <- list.dirs(parent.folder, recursive=FALSE)
filt.folders = sub.folders[grepl("SV-14", sub.folders)]
filt.folders =filt.folders[grepl("S2", filt.folders)]
```

I would like to code to make a list with SV-14-xxx_S2 and SV-14-xxx_S1 samples. So basically, the pattern should look like 'SV-14' and ('S1' or 'S2').

and create:

SV-14-001_S1
SV-14-001_S2
SV-14-002_S1
SV-14-001_S2
SV-14-003_S1
etc.

Comment: Try `"^SV-14-[^_]*_S[12]"`

Comment: it does not give an error, but gives a _character (empty)_

Comment: it worked! I deleted the ^ before the SV and now it makes axactly the correct list. Thank you Wiktor

Answer (score 2):

To build your main pattern, you may use character classes:

```
"SV-14-[^_]*_S[12]"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tRbAgS/1).

It will match `SV-14-`, then any 0 or more chars other than `_`, then a `_` and then `S` and `1` or `2`.

If you want to match it as a whole subdirectory, you need to account for `/` or `\` chars:

```
"([\\\\/]|^)SV-14-[^_]*_S[12]([\\\\/]|$)"
```

where `([\\\\/]|^)` matches `\` or `/` or start of string and `([\\\\/]|$)` matches `\`, `/` or end of string.

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tRbAgS/2).